# How do I figure out the sequence of a custom Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

```
x=1:1
x=2:2
x=3:3
x=4:6
x=5:9
x=6:15
x=7:25
x=8:39
x=9:63
x=10:99
```

I've tried using the normal Fibonacci sequence although there were always slight small differences in the numbers.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does $x=4$ get $6?$ It is unclear what you mean by “custom Fibonacci sequence.”

Comment: This appears to be [A114323](http://oeis.org/A114323), $\lceil \sqrt[5]
{10^n}\rceil -1 $

Comment: I was told this was a custom Fibonacci sequence, therefore x=4 getting 6 is normal

Comment: @lulu im quite sure that's the answer, could you post it so I can mark it as correct? Much appreciated, thank you so much for answering the question!

Comment: Well, it is definitely not a “custom Fibonacci sequence” under any definition I know. I suppose it is an integer sequence with exponential growth, but otherwise, I don’t think it has much to do with Fibonacci. There certainly isn’t a linear recursion for the sequence, for example.

Comment: I would expect from a "custom Fibonacci sequence"  that we have $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ for every integer $n\ge 3$. Otherwise the terminology does not really make sense. If we add , for example  , the last three numbers, we would have a "custom Tribonacci sequence".

Comment: Since we cannot find a Fibonacci-pattern, we can only guess what the general term of this sequence is. The answer below gives a so-called "reasonable guess", but we do not know whether the sequence continues this way.

Comment: Hi, very sorry that I got slightly confused over if this was a Fibonacci pattern, I was given a hint that this may be a Fibonacci sequence, therefore I posted it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [A114323](http://oeis.org/A114323), $a_n$ is the largest natural number such that $a_n^5$ has $n$ digits.

It can be expressed as $$a_n=\big \lceil \sqrt[5]
{10^n}\big \rceil -1$$